TypeError: test.run_game() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
I am attempting to refactor a pygame moduel "test.py" into a class. I expect it to crate the a (500,500) pygame screen and exit properly. Before refactoring it works perfectly. There is a function called 'run_game()' that contains the while loop and the exit procedure.
When the class is executed I get 'TypeError:
test.run_game() missing 1 required positional argument :'self'

...
import pygame
import sys
class test:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self.define_screen()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl = test
    cl.run_game()


The error you're encountering is due to how you're trying to call the run_game method on your class instance. You need to create an instance of the test class first and then call the run_game method on that instance.

Also define_screen is not provided. Should class test inherit some? You will get another error after fixing current issue: https://pastebin.com/fp42V2py

I think cl should be object of class test, not class test instance. Fix line #13:
cl = test()

instead
cl = test


"Everything is object" paradigm in python may confuse beginners:

cl = test means cl is "alias" for class test (not correct in your case);
cl = test() means cl is instance with class test (correct in your case).

More details here: Is everything an object in Python like Ruby?

Thanks, When I saw the answer, I felt stupid. It's amazing when frustration sets in, one's vision can narrow. It works perfectly.

Glad to help, @david-underwood. If my answer helped you, may you vote for it please? Thank you too.
